# Calling a function from external JS where that function needs to make changes on another page

Tags: javascript, html, sitemap

I'm quite new to js
what I'm trying to do is I have 2 web pages one is a gallery page and other is a site map.

On the gallery page I have 5 small images and a one large image with a description below it. When a user clicks on a small image the large image gets replaced with that image user clicked on and the description changed accordingly.  I have done this by calling onclick functions on an external js file.

What I can't do my self is there should be links on the site map to view each small image on the big image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URL GET parameters. On your sitemap page set href attributes for you image links in this way:

```
<a href="index.html?image=image1"></a>
<a href="index.html?image=image2"></a>
<a href="index.html?image=image3"></a>
```

Then for your image page use script to get image parameter. I used the universal function to get all parameters and then checked image one.

```
function getAllParams () {
var allParams = {};
var query = window.location.search.slice(1);
if (query) {
    query = query.split('#')[0]; //all after # is not a part of query
    var arr = query.split('&'); // split our query string into its component parts
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var pair = arr[i].split('='); // separate the keys and the values
        allParams[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]); //add query and its value to allParams obj
    }
}

return allParams; 
}

var allParams = getAllParams();

if (allParams.image === 'image1') {
    //show your image1 as a big image
}
```